# d3.csv returns index.html content in console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, d3.js

I am using d3 v5 with reactJS. I am calling d3.csv inside react 'List' class like following:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

class List extends React.Component{

componentDidMount(){
d3.csv("./data/data.csv").then(function(d, error){
    console.log(d);
});
}

render(){
        return(
        <div> </div>
        );
    }
} 
  export default List;
```

and List is being imported in following 'App' class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import List from './components/list/List';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>          
        <List/> 
      </div>      
    );
  }
}
 export default App;
```

Following is the 'index.js' code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

'root' is a div id in index.html. By calling console.log in List file inside d3.csv I am getting content of index.html file in the console. But I want CSV content.

[image]

Comment: @altocumulus now I have posted clearly what the issue is. Please help if you understand the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using the **import** statement to load the CSV file at first. :)

```
import React from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import data from "./data/data.csv";

class List extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    d3.csv(data).then(function(d, error){
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log(d);
      };
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div> </div>
    );
  }
} 

export default List;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and here's how I solved it. Check if the data is in the same directory as the `index.html` file. In my case, my `index.html` file is in the `public/` folder, so I created `public/data/data.csv`. You can then try `d3.csv('./data/data', function(data){...})` to read in the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hooks and useState, ensure that the URL is a string and not resolved as an object before using the data.

[Before Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dOcx.png)

[Before Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNIgi.png)

[After Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ7Wc.png)

[After Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7fGg.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).